# encode data to send to a websocket server

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, websocket

after attempting to connect to a websocket server and send information to it i am running in to an encoding issue.
i have a string and the encoded(hex) version of this string. Lets say my string is `'getpremium'` how do I convert that string into an array of these hex values?

```
[0x81, 0x8c, 0x86, 0x78, 0xe3, 0xc6, 0xe1, 0x1d,
0x97, 0xb6, 0xf4, 0x1d, 0x8e, 0xaf, 0xf3, 0x15,
0xee, 0xcc]
```

I can decode these values back in to the original string, but I am at a loss as to how they are encoded in to these hex values. Basically how can i encode that string 'getpremium' to get those encoded values as to send them to this websocket server. Any method using either python or node.js is applicable.

javascript decoding method:

```
var _ = require("underscore");
function decode(data){
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
                data = _.map(data, function(chr){ return chr.charCodeAt(0); });
        }
        var datalength = data[1] & 127;
        var indexFirstMask = 2;
        if (datalength == 126) {
                indexFirstMask = 4;
        } else if (datalength == 127) {
                indexFirstMask = 10;
        }
        var masks = data.slice(indexFirstMask,indexFirstMask + 4);
        var i = indexFirstMask + 4;
        var index = 0;
        var output = "";
        while (i < data.length) {
                x = data[i++] ^ masks[index++ % 4];
                output += String.fromCharCode(x);
        }
        return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

def encode(rawBytes):
    data = [ord(i) for i in rawBytes]
    length = len(rawBytes) + 128
    Bytes = [0x81, length]
    index = 2
    masks = os.urandom(4)
    for i in range(len(masks)):
           Bytes.insert(i + index, masks[i])        
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= masks[i % 4]
        Bytes.insert(i + index + 4, data[i])
    return [hex(i) for i in Bytes]
```